# $SU(3)$ global gauge group

Tags: group-representations, quarks, color-charge

Referring to the quantum observables of quarks, is it true that the color $SU(3)$ unitary representation commutes with all observables?

I am not referring here to the *local* $SU(3)$ gauge theory, I am just considering the *global* color $SU(3)$ symmetry.

My problem is that, if it were the case, it would not possible to distinguish a pair of apparently different (pure) states represented by unit vectors $\Psi$, $\Psi'$ if $\Psi' = U\Psi$ when  $U$ is such a gauge transformation, by means of any sort of measurement. Indeed if $A$ is an observable $$\langle \Psi'|A \Psi' \rangle = \langle U\Psi|A U\Psi \rangle =  \langle \Psi|U^*A U\Psi \rangle = \langle \Psi|A U^*U\Psi \rangle = \langle \Psi|A \Psi \rangle\:.$$    In other words $U$ plays the exact role of phases in QM  when the algebra of observables is the whole class of selfadjoint operators. In this respect, states should be re-defined as equivalence classes $[\Psi]$ with respect to the equivalence under the action of color $SU(3)$.

Conversely, I have read that the color degrees of freedom have been introduced (also) to fix problems with the spin statistic principle.

There are  states $\Psi$ of hadrons composed of three quarks which seem to be symmetric under swap of particles in spite of the fact that quarks are fermions.   Adding an antisymmetric color part $\Phi_{color}$ to the state, the complete state  $\Psi \otimes  \Phi_{color}$ satisfies the spin statistic principle. Here the color $SU(3)$ representation just acts on the part $\Phi_{color}$ of the state.

Assuming I have understood well, I am not sure to agree with this idea because as the part $\Phi_{color}$ is *a priori* unobservable it cannot play any physical role and it cannot be used to fix problems with Pauli principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the gauge theory is quantized in the proper way, you cannot even meaningfully talk about the action of an $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ transformation on the space of states because the quantization of a gauge theory essentially requires you to *quotient out the gauge transformations* (all of them, including the global ones), so that they are "do nothing" transformations on the actual physical states. In particular, the question of whether the gauge transformations commute with all observables becomes trivial as the gauge transformations are the identity on the space of physical states.

Now, the introduction of color solves the spin-statistic problem by building the state of space fully *before* quotienting out the transformations. On the gauge-variant "pre-physical states", you can build the well-known colorless state consisting of three quarks. Since it is gauge-invariant as a colorless pre-physical state, quotienting out the transformations when passing the true physical Hilbert space does nothing to it, and it is therefore still there after that.

A bit more technically (I might be cheating here because you *really* need to carry out the BRST procedure to get the physical space of states), on the pre-physical space you have three different fermionic creation operators $a^\dagger_b,a^\dagger_g,a^\dagger_r$ associated to the triplet-valued fermionic fields. The spin-statistic theorem essentially says that each of these anticommutes with itself, and hence gives zero when squared, but it doesn't forbid applying each of them once to the vacuum. After quotienting out the gauge transformations, these operators don't descend to well-defined operator on the quotient exactly because they are not invariant under the group action we quotiented out, and nothing forces that the image of the colorless pre-physical three-quark state $a^\dagger_b a^\dagger_g a^\dagger_r \lvert 0\rangle$ in the quotient should vanish - and indeed it doesn't.

Comment: I do  not understand well. Is the space of states a Hilbert space, after taking the quotient? If the answer is positive, is a *true* vector state of quarks antisymmetric under interchange of identical particles?

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Yes, the quotient is there to *make* it a Hilbert space, actually. The space before the quotient has zero norm states as well as negative norm "ghost states" in it, which we get rid of by the quotient and turn the pre-physical pseudo-inner product space into an actual Hilbert space. The formal procedure is called BRST quantization and is rather subtle to get right in full generality.

Comment: I understand, it is similar to what happens in QED with Gupta-Bleuler formalism.

Comment: So it is false a claim, sometimes stated in the literature, that QCD is an example where the von Neumann algebra of observables is not $B(H)$  but a smaller factor with non-Abelian commutant!

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Yes indeed, Gupta-Bleuler is the version of that that works only for Abelian gauge theories.

Comment: I know a bit of BRST formalism ("B" was my lecturer on theoretical physics :-) ), but I was thinking that the problem of $SU(3)$ color *global* gauge were independent form QFT...The picture is more complicated...thanks

Comment: I am back on this question because there is a point I cannot understand in your answer. The initial space of states (including the non physical ones) is however a vector space regardless the fact that it includes states with non-positive norm. After several quotient procedures, you say, one obtains the physical Hilbert space. I cannot see how to completely remove the global gauge group this way. The equivalence relation $\psi \sim \psi'$ iff $\psi =U\psi'$ for some $U \in SU(3)$ (or every other gauge group) does not preserve the additive structure of the vector space.

Comment: Indeed even in QED, dealing with the (non covariant)  most physical gauge which selects  only the transverse degrees of freedom defining a proper Fock- Hilbert space, the global U (1) gauge remains. Observables are the elements of spinor field algebra commuting with the U (1) rep generated by the electric charge operator.

Comment: @ValterMoretti You are right, my formulation is somewhat misleading: We do not merely "quotient out" the gauge transformation from the Hilbert space, but we *select the subset of states that are gauge invariant*, i.e. the physical space of states is $\bigcap_a \ker(T^a)$ for the generators $T^a$ of gauge transformations (the constraints in the Hamiltonian formalism). This is sometimes inconsistent, and in the Fock space we only choose the "annihilation part" of these constraints. To implement the "second half", we *then* have to quotient out by null spurious states.

Comment: @ValterMoretti: As for the remaining global symmetry in electromagnetism, note that a constant U(1) transformation *does not actually change the gauge*, since the first term in $A\mapsto gAg^{-1} + g^{-1} dg$ always collapses to $A$, so constant U(1) transformations are not gauge transformations in a proper sense, while I think they *are* for non-Abelian gauge groups since $gAg^{-1}$ does change the gauge even for constant $g$.

Comment: @ ACuriousMind  Many thanks. I also agree with your second comment. from the QFT viewpoint the transformation is not a gauge transformation, but it is if referring to the theory of algebras of operators. There is a little confusion of languages. However I was referring to the action of the gauge group on the fields describing the matter not on the gauge fields themselves.